# Passing attributes to in force:navigateToURL or force:createRecord

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How to pass default value to Event object with Lightning Components
e.g. Passing one default account to Name field is displayed while new event record is creating

Comment: url hacking in lightning standard page... no you can't do that..

Comment: how could i achieve this kind of functionality, if sforce.one.navigatetoURL and lightening components wont support.

Comment: Raj_SFDC....currently there no possible way to achieve this functionality..

Comment: Thank you , but i hope this kind of feature will be advantage us